# Slow access to AcroFields (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, itext, acrofields

I'm using iTextSharp to extract SignatureNames from a PDF.
I encountered problems (excessive slowness) accessing AcroFiels of big size and many pages PDF (~40MB and ~5000 pages).

Here my code snippet:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

private static List<byte[]> GetSignsFromPDF(string filePath)
{
    var result = new List<byte[]>();
    var randomAccessFileOrArray = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filePath);
    var reader = new PdfReader(randomAccessFileOrArray, null);
    var fields = reader.AcroFields;

    if (fields == null)
    {
        return result;
    }

    var signatureNames = fields.GetSignatureNames();
    signatureNames.Sort();

    foreach (string name in signatureNames)
    {
        var sigDict = fields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
        var contents = sigDict.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);

        if (contents != null)
        {
            result.Add(contents.GetOriginalBytes());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

There is a smarter/faster way to access AcroFields or should I wait iTextSharp stuff?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by *excessive slowness*. And if possible share a link to a sample PDF for analysis.

Comment: For _excessive slowness_ i mean about **20-60 minutes** of waiting time both debugging in VS both in release on production machine. I try to find a  PDF that I can share here because the only one that have problems contains sensible customer's datas.

Comment: Ok, that **is** excessive slowness. :) I have not yet experienced such slowness with iText(Sharp). Thus, there quite likely indeed is something special about those pdfs.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a test case that can be more exhaustive. I generate a random text **PDF with 1852 pages and 11,1Mb size**. I tried to access AcroFields of this and it takes <1ms time (and 0 AcroFields found). I tried to sign this PDF and to access AcroFields and now it takes around 45 seconds. So maybe the "problem" is that **iTextSharp looks for AcroFields browsing all pages** (or something similar i guess)?

Comment: *iTextSharp looks for AcroFields browsing all pages* - It does... for compatibility reasons. There used to be some PDF form creating products which did **not** add all the fields into the **AcroForm** form field tree but only referenced their appearances as annotations from the document pages.

Comment: Oh, good. Well, you know if there is a _smarter_ way to access Signature fields than `var signatureNames = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();` ? All examples and tutorial on iTextSharp show indicate that code but, I hope, I'm not the first one that manage **signed pdf with a thousand of pages**...

Comment: *Well, you know if there is a smarter way to access Signature fields* - Not in general (because in general one has to consider files with not properly linked form fields). Depending on what you know about your files, though, there are some shortcuts.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the whole PDF in memory (i.e. using a `PdfReader` constructor that does not use partial mode)? That quite likely would speed things up a bit if searching those many pages indeed are the cause of the slowness...

Comment: _Have you tried keeping the whole PDF in memory_: Yes I did. But I'm using `PdfReader` constructor from `string filename` to `RandomAccessFileOrArray` because with the first one, in some cases, i receive an unhandled exception of type `System.StackOverflowException` in `itextsharp.dll`

Comment: Well, obviously you will need more resources, but access should be fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments the conjecture came up that the *excessive slowness* is due to the fact that iText(Sharp) during initialization of the field collection in an `AcroFields` instance not only inspects the fields referenced in **Catalog** -> **AcroForm** -> **Fields** but also (actually foremost) from the **ANNOTS** of all document pages.

Fortunately this initialization does not take place in the `AcroFields` constructor, so we can inject a field collection retrieved without inspecting all the pages.

The following method is a copy of the internal `AcroFields` method `Fill` (which is responsible for the lazy initialization) with the page traversal removed and with access to hidden members enabled via reflection. It can be used to test the conjecture.

```
void fill(PdfReader reader, AcroFields acroFields)
{
    IDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item> fields = new LinkedDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item>();
    PdfDictionary top = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(reader.Catalog.Get(PdfName.ACROFORM));
    if (top == null)
        return;
    PdfBoolean needappearances = top.GetAsBoolean(PdfName.NEEDAPPEARANCES);
    if (needappearances == null || !needappearances.BooleanValue)
        acroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
    else
        acroFields.GenerateAppearances = false;
    PdfArray arrfds = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(top.Get(PdfName.FIELDS));
    if (arrfds == null || arrfds.Size == 0)
        return;

    System.Reflection.FieldInfo valuesField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("values", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo widgetsField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("widgets", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo widgetRefsField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("widget_refs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo mergedField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("merged", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo pageField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("page", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo tabOrderField = typeof(AcroFields.Item).GetField("tabOrder", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    for (int j = 0; j < arrfds.Size; ++j)
    {
        PdfDictionary annot = arrfds.GetAsDict(j);
        if (annot == null)
        {
            PdfReader.ReleaseLastXrefPartial(arrfds.GetAsIndirectObject(j));
            continue;
        }
        if (!PdfName.WIDGET.Equals(annot.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
        {
            PdfReader.ReleaseLastXrefPartial(arrfds.GetAsIndirectObject(j));
            continue;
        }
        PdfArray kids = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(annot.Get(PdfName.KIDS));
        if (kids != null)
            continue;
        PdfDictionary dic = new PdfDictionary();
        dic.Merge(annot);
        PdfString t = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
        if (t == null)
            continue;
        String name = t.ToUnicodeString();
        if (fields.ContainsKey(name))
            continue;
        AcroFields.Item item = new AcroFields.Item();
        fields[name] = item;
        ((List<PdfDictionary>)valuesField.GetValue(item)).Add(dic); // item.AddValue(dic);
        ((List<PdfDictionary>)widgetsField.GetValue(item)).Add(dic); // item.AddWidget(dic);
        ((List<PdfIndirectReference>)widgetRefsField.GetValue(item)).Add(arrfds.GetAsIndirectObject(j)); //item.AddWidgetRef(arrfds.GetAsIndirectObject(j)); // must be a reference
        ((List<PdfDictionary>)mergedField.GetValue(item)).Add(dic); // item.AddMerged(dic);
        ((List<int>)pageField.GetValue(item)).Add((int)-1); // item.AddPage(-1);
        ((List<int>)tabOrderField.GetValue(item)).Add((int)-1); // item.AddTabOrder(-1);
    }

    System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldsField = typeof(AcroFields).GetField("fields", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    fieldsField.SetValue(acroFields, fields);
}
```

It should be called for an `AcroFields` instance  as early as possible, e.g.:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file))
{
    AcroFields acroFields = reader.AcroFields;
    fill(reader, acroFields);
    ...
```

If using this method reduces the time considerably (while at the same time supplying the desired fields), the conjecture is confirmed.

---

Looking at the code one recognizes that it does not properly walk the field structure: Fields may be arranged hierarchically but the code only considers the first level elements. It should suffice for a first test of the conjecture mentioned above, though.